# Use SHA256 Signing XML algorithm in .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, xml-signature

I am trying to sign an `XML EBICS` file with `SHA256` algorithm. I can't use the `.Net Framework 4.5` in my project.

In the `.NET 4.5` we can write the code below,

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
```

So I've no idea how I can did it in `.Net 4.0`

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at CLR Security
https://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.dll&referringTitle=Home

The RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription class has been implemented in that assembly, built in .NET 3.5, hence must work in .NET 4.0

Comment: I try to add the library and I follow this guide : https://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription&referringTitle=Security.Cryptography.dll 
But I have a problem, when I try to reference it with `gacutil ` but i get an error because the assembly don't have a strong name.

Comment: Edit : I finally successfully reference it with gautil but now i already have the same problem that i had previously : i get an error message : "invalid specified Algorithm"

Comment: @ThomasRollet: same problem here. How did you solve it?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia I used the library provided by Don in the answer